# How to use bootstrap to make text + image responsive side by side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a paragraph float to the left, while an image floats to the right.

(working demo -> https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6557/)

There will be some paragraphs without an image, so I was wondering how I would be able to make this responsive. As of now, when I resize the window, nothing stacks or changes.

I wanted to incorporate using

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
<div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working the way I want it to. Thank you!

Comment: Do you not know in advance which rows with have an image or not?

Comment: i know which one's have images or not

Comment: Your working demo does not have the Bootstrap CSS included nor the markup you posted above

Comment: ^Exactly what I noticed too lol @Ave Please post a jsfiddle with the col-md version which you said is not working please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/42/ with text on the left and an image on the right and they seem to be stacking as they should.

I think the reason why your columns are not stacking is probably because you didn't link your bootstrap files properly (on the jsfiddle you made and most probably in your html file too).

Try adding this line to your `<head>....</head>` section:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And check if that helps.